# How do I fix remote Git commands after messing with proxy settings?

Tags: git

My Git was pushing without problem to our internal Git server, eg, this was working fine:

```
$ git push origin master
```

Today I wanted to work with a project hosted on Github, so I had to temporarily add in our company's proxy settings to get it to connect:

```
$ git config --global http.proxy http://myusername:mypwd@ourproxy.com:8080
```

This worked, but now I'm done and need to connect back to our internal server again.  Now, when pushing internally, I get this:

```
$ git push origin master
fatal: repository 'http://me@ourserver.com/scm/~me/myrepository.
git/' not found
```

So then I tried removing the proxy settings:

```
$ git config --global --unset core.gitproxy
$ git config --unset core.gitproxy
```

But still get 'reposititory not found', and in fact any remote commands, to either new repositories I create or existing ones that were working before, give the same error.

What should I try next to fix this?

Comment: Did that command remove proxy part in `~/.gitconfig`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unset `http.proxy`:

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
```